# How to pass instance variables through link_to, to call js file, which renders a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance, partial-views

My app consists of four models. User > List > Wish < Item. I'm showing all the items on the front page, and want to be able to build a wish from the individual items.

Because of the associations I have to enable to user to specify which list he want to associate the item with. I want to do through an ajax call and a modal. However, the instance variable `item` in the `_item.html.erb` partial can't be passed through a `link_to`, which calls `app/views/wishes/new.js.erb`, which renders a form to specify the list.

I'm very new to rails and ruby, and this problem have been troubling me for days! Any help is thus much appreciated.

The associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :wishes, through: :lists
  has_many :items, through: :wishes
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :wishes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :wishes
end

class Wish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list, touch: true
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishes
  has_many :lists, through: :wishes
end
```

app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

```
<%= render @items %>
```

app/views/items/_item.html.erb

```
<div class="span4">
    <div class="white-box item">
        <div class="image-container">
            <%= link_to "Wishlistt it", new_wish_path(item_id: item.id), id: "new_wish", class: "btn btn-primary btn-large", remote: true %>
            <a href="<%= item_path(item) %>" class="item-link">
                <em class="mark"></em>
                <%= image_tag item.image_url(:medium).to_s %>
            </a>
        </div>
        <h3><%= item.title %></h3>
        <%= item.wishes.count %> wishes this item

    </div>
</div>
```

app/views/wishes/new.js.erb

```
$('body').append('<%= j render "new_wish" %>');
$('#new_wish').modal('toggle')
```

app/views/wishes/_new_wish.html.erb

```
<div id="new_wish" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="make_wish" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="wishlistt_it">Wishlistt it</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="linkpreview">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= form_for(@item.wishes.build(item_id: @item.id)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :item_id %>
        <%= f.label :list_id %>
        <%= select_tag :list_id, options_for_select(current_user.lists.all.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }) %>
        <%= f.submit "Add wish", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <%= link_to "Get info", new_item_path, id: "urlb", class: "btn btn-primary", remote: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pressing the link from `_item.html.erb` raises this error:

```
undefined method `wishes&#x27; for nil:NilClass
```

**EDIT**

wishes_controller.rb

```
class WishesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def new
    @wish = Wish.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.find_by_id(params[:item_id])
    @wish = Wish.create!(item_id: params[:wish][:item_id], list_id: params[:list_id])
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
    @wish.destroy
    redirect_to current_user
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @wish = current_user.wishes.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to current_user if @wish.nil?
    end
end
```

Comment: there are two links in _item.html.erb, which exacty causes error? (by the way, why don't you use link_to helper on second link?)

Comment: It's the first link_to helper. Good point - will change that :)

Comment: Actually, in this case controller methods more useful, than models code, please show new wish controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, how path_heplers work.

```
new_wish_path
```

will produce route

```
/wishes/new
```

which, for default, will be looking for `wishes#new` method, which you actually don't have.

`New` action is needed to GET object form, and `create` method saves inputed data in database - this is default Rails logic.

Here you don't have form, that means, you don't pass `params[:wish]`(it is nil).

Also, in create method you need to use `save` method, which saves inputed data to DB.

In conclusion, in my opinion, this code is really far enough from something that can be edited and that can work normally. Anyway, I recommend to refactor this code following provided here tips, from very beggining, it will save you time for sure.

**UPD**

Steps to fix:

1) add `new` method in wishes_contoller

2) define there instance `@item` for form, finding it by params in request: `@item = Item.find_by_id(params[:item_id])`

Comment: I implemented your suggestions -  however, it still yields the same error. I've tried another version with the form from `_new_wish.html.erb` directly in the `_item.html.erb` partial, which works fine (the `@item` swapped with `item` in the form)

Comment: Try this in _new_wish.html.erb, before form `@item=Item.new`

Comment: This makes the error go away. However, I don't want to create a new Item, just the association (Wish) between a List and an Item.

Comment: That is just connected with my answer idea - error occures because, without new method, @item is undefined. And define it in view is bad practice. About build method. You don't need form to create assosiation itself, it's done through controller. And you need to build object in object from very beggining (when you create this object).

Comment: Your answers and comments led me in the right direction - had to create the `new` method in the `wishes_controller.rb` and specify `@item = Item.find_by_id(params[:item_id])`. If you update your answer accordingly, I can accept it, and give you credit